# Can libraries share memory as in linux?

Tags: processes, background-process

Is it possible for libraries to share memory like the shared memory in linux?
(The shared memory feature adopted in System V and later adopted to linux)

Eg: When two apps are working simultaneously and both uses the OkHttp library, is the library loaded into memory twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same shared memory feature is still present in Android, and it works on built-in shared libraries such as OpenGL ES, but it's not used for third-party libraries like you're asking about. Each app that uses a third-party library has to include the library in its APK file. These then aren't shared libraries (in the `.so` sense): they're just duplicate files which might happen to contain the same code. (Usually they won't contain the same code because different apps will have been built against different versions of the library.)

This avoids possible incompatibilities or security problems caused by updating libraries from different apps. Shared library incompatibilities are a huge problem in GNU/Linux systems. Distributions put a lot of effort into preventing them by testing different combinations of applications and libraries, but they still go wrong sometimes. In Android, where nobody is responsible for making sure that different apps work together, that kind of shared library system would result in apps often breaking when a shared library is updated. Security problems might come about in a system that used shared libraries in this way, because an app might update a shared library to a "newer version" that's actually hacked to leak information or control the app. The libraries would have to be treated as separate packages, signed by the author, just like apps are, and then there would have to be a complex process for handling version updates.

Comment: With pre-installed "core libraries" being the exception, I assume?

Comment: I don't think that core libraries have an exception in this case.

Comment: This is incorrect. Just like Linux, Android creates a copy-on-write mmap of the libraries, the kernel will automatically share the memory for mmap when possible. All core system libraries are also loaded by zygote and shared when a new process is forked. [Reference](http://elinux.org/Android_Memory_Usage).

Comment: @LieRyan The page you're referring to is only talking about the built-in "Android framework" libraries, not third-party libraries like the OP asks about. It's even better than just sharing the binaries: the COW process applies to the whole heap before the zygote fork. The same technique *could* be used for third-party libraries but in practice doesn't work out well on Android because the (third-party) libraries aren't actually built as shared libraries - they're distinct copies, statically linked. It would have to read the whole binary to know whether the library can be shared or not.

Comment: Java doesn't really have statically linked libraries, all classes are dynamically linked. In any case, the reason libraries included in an application don't actually share memory isn't because they're statically linked, but rather because applications ships their own copy of the libraries which then exists as different files in the filesystem. Shared libraries need to be loaded from the same file if they want to share memory. The AOT compiler may also inline library calls, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @LieRyan Yes, that was my original point. If you can think of a better way to describe this that end users will understand, I'd be happy to accept an edit.

Comment: @DanHulme you have highlighted a security error in the answer but the shared memory is present in linux without any such errors. Any clarification would be awesome.